# How to guarantee copy elision with std::variant?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, copy-elision

I have this type:

```
struct immobile {
   // other stuff omitted
   immobile(immobile&) = delete;
   immobile(immobile&&) = delete;
};
immobile mk_immobile();
// e.g. this compiles
// mk_immobile() is a prvalue and i is its result object
immobile i(mk_immobile());
```

I also have this class template:

```
template<typename T>
struct container {
    std::variant<T, other_stuff> var;
    template<typename... Args>
    container(Args&&... args)
    : var(std::in_place_index<0>, std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

I want to construct a `container` around the object produced by `mk_immobile()`, with the `immobile` object used to initialize one of the variants of `var`.

```
container<immobile> c(mk_immobile());
```

However, this does not work. For one, `std::variant`'s constructor wants `std::is_constructible_v<immobile, immobile>`, which doesn't hold. Worse, even this simplified version fails:

```
template<typename T>
struct demonstration {
    T t;
    template<typename... Args>
    demonstration(Args&&... args) : t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
demonstration<immobile> d(mk_immobile());
```

Which seems to imply that `std::forward` does not, in fact, perfectly forward—prvalues do not forward as prvalues. (This makes sense to me; I don't think doing that would be possible.) I can make `demonstration` work by changing it to this:

```
template<typename T>
struct demonstration {
    T t;
    template<typename F>
    demonstration(F&& f) : t(std::forward<F>(f)()) {}
};
demonstration<immobile> d([] { return mk_immobile(); });
```

But I do not see a way to change `container` in a similar manner. How do I change `container` so that it can construct a `std::variant` (or other tagged union) out of a prvalue? I can change `container` but cannot change `immobile`.

Comment: From a quick test: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/27cALe It seems like it should be possible to implement a tagged union that behaves the way you want, by using your defered callback-based construction idea (I just did a much simpler version of the same thing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You abuse casts

```
template<typename F>
struct initializer
{
    F f;
    template<typename T>
    operator T()
    {
        return f();
    }
};

template<typename F>
initializer(F&&) -> initializer<F>;
```

And use as

```
container<immobile> c{initializer{[]{
    return mk_immobile();
}}};
```

Comment: I like it! However, I think `initializer` might need two changes to make it forward more perfectly. I think `F f` should be `F&& f` and `f()` should be `std::forward<F>(f)()`. Functors can use perfect forwarding because `operator()` can be present in both `&`-qualified and `&&`-qualified versions, and forwarding allows more fitting overload resolution. `initializer`s are only meant to be used once, so I think it's safe to allow the functor to move itself away. See [this example](https://www.godbolt.org/z/rWWUrA). Is this change a good idea?

Comment: @HTNW I don't hink that's a good idea. You are increasing the risk of accidentally creating a dangling reference just for the sake of explicitely doing an optimization  that any compiler would do by itself anyways.

Comment: It's possible for `operator() &` and `operator() &&` to be different; I don't think the change is an optimization. I can actually use `v_initializer { [] { return std::forward<F>(f)(); } }` (`initializer` as posted by @PasserBy) to emulate the behavior of `fw_initializer { std::forward<F>(f)(); }` (`initializer` as modified by me). I don't think you can accidentally invoke move semantics with either; you need to both use `std::move` and either write the custom lambda or use `std::forward`.

Comment: @HTNW `F&& f` is almost certainly a mistake, you now have a dangling reference whenever `initializer` is used outside its full expression. You may forward `f` even without the reference.

Comment: OK, so to sum up: if I have `F f` where `F` is immobile and want a `container` built with `f()`, I cannot construct your `initializer` with `f` in it, but I can either capture `f` as a reference in a lambda or make `initializer` hold a reference (`&` or `&&`—there's apparently no difference) itself. I need *a* reference, somewhere, and a dangling reference is inevitable if `f` gets destroyed. However, your `initializer` disallows accidentally using a temporary for `f`, removing one possible source of such references. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Unfortunately this trick does not work with MSVC.
https://godbolt.org/z/3eT8549f5 If you add back the copy and move constructor then the code works. https://godbolt.org/z/dK9oW3hEr

Comment: @bradgonesurfing That is a MSVC bug. MSVC thinks `std::is_constructible_v` is false but a variable declaration with the same types fine.