# Is there a bug in the Microsoft version of std::variant?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, compiler-bug, std-variant

With regards to the advice in this answer: [How to guarantee copy elision with std::variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435914/how-to-guarantee-copy-elision-with-stdvariant) discovered after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77228577/is-it-possible-to-emplace-a-non-copyable-non-moveable-into-a-stdvariant) was closed.

TLDR: MSVC doesn't work with the advice given.

https://godbolt.org/z/r7Pr6eG1j

I have reduced my code to the following minimal example.

```cpp
#include <variant>

struct Foo {
    int x;
    Foo(int _x):x(_x){}
    Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
};

using Storage = std::variant<std::monostate,Foo>;

template <typename F>
struct initializer {
    F f;
    template <typename T>
    operator T() const { 
        return f();
    }
};

template<class F>
initializer(F) -> initializer<F>;

Foo make_foo(){
    return Foo{10};
}

int main() {
    Storage s2;
    s2.emplace<1>(initializer{make_foo});
}
```

The code attempts to insert the non-copyable and non-movable type `Foo` into the `variant` by way of the wrapper type `initializer`. This pattern works for gcc and clang, but not for MSVC.

https://godbolt.org/z/r7Pr6eG1j

Is this a bug in the MSVC implementation of `std::variant`, or is the advice given in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435914/how-to-guarantee-copy-elision-with-stdvariant) reliant on implementation defined behaviour?

Is there a workaround for MSVC?

[image]

Comment: Latest MSVC on godbolt does compile this. If I had to guess, it's [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/2620), which I also faced when implementing the same hack for [this library](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/better_braces).

Comment: Seems fixed in 19.33 https://godbolt.org/z/b7jbsr7rG

Comment: Hmm, my library starts working properly in 19.34, so that's not it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That is a cool library.